# Create a Java library (jar) from C code

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Greetings,

I am trying to use this api:
http://code.google.com/p/vavi-sensor/

for using the macbook accelerometer in Java code.

I am put the .c files into my library but I am still getting a 
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SmsWrapper in java.library.path`

I assume this is because it's still in .c files while all my other libraries are .jar. How can I go about getting this into a jar or other loadable format (jnilib, etc)?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).  JNA is easier, but you still need to compile the C as a library, then follow the [JNA documentation](http://jna.java.net/#getting_started).

Answer (score 0):

The .c files are just source code.  You need them compiled for the appropriate machine, packaged into a shared object library, and then referenced by native methods in a wrapper Java class.

[The JNI tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html) has all the information you'll need, although it doesn't go into detail about the non-Java side of things as most people doing this already know about programming in C and building shared object libraries.